# XPages server validation errors haven't been displayed to the user

Tags: xpages, lotus-domino, xpages-ssjs

We are working with Domino 8.5.3 and we noticed an issue with xpages validation messages being displayed on the server console.

Here is a simple xpage we created to re-create the issue:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xp:view xmlns:xp="http://www.ibm.com/xsp/core">

    <xp:inputText id="inputText1" required="true">
        <xp:this.validators>
            <xp:validateRequired message="Value is required."></xp:validateRequired>
        </xp:this.validators>
    </xp:inputText>

    <xp:messages id="messages1"></xp:messages>
</xp:view>
```

Even though we have a xp:messages on the page and we are able to see those error messages on the xpage, we also see them displayed on the server console! Has anyone else noticed this?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Do you have 'disableClientSideValidation' set to true?  I am unclear from the question if the xp:messages is showing messages.   You definitely want that set to true for the xp:messages to work.

Comment: I just played with this in my latest app, and the client side validation has no effect on writing to the server console.  It does prevent messages from being shown in the xp:messages.  I have never heard of those messages being written to the server console.  Sorry to ask the obvious, but do you have a print() or System.out.println() in the code somewhere?

Comment: Another thing on what triggers the update, is it set to 'Do not validate or update data' or 'Process data without validation'?  --- BTW: Earlier when I commented, I didn't see in your question title that indeed the users weren't seeing the messages, which is what I was assuming anyway.

Comment: Hi Steve, many thanks for a prompt response, we don't have disableClientSideValidation set to true, as a matter of fact, we don't use it. We have turned off client side validation at the application level through xsp properties. My apologies for not being clear, the users are seeing the message, but it's printed on the server console as well. No we don't have print or System.out.println anywhere. We don't even have a submit button on the xpage as you can see from the source listed above, all we are doing is pressing enter in that field to submit the data.

Comment: Wild guess:  In the XSP properties, try changing "Client Validation" from "Off" to "Server Default" and then make sure it is turned off in the edit control.

Comment: Thanks Steve, we have already tried that. Are you able to reproduce this issue on your server? It would be interesting to know if this issue is on our server only or whether other people are experiencing this as well.

Comment: I will go ahead and give it a try and let you know.  Our server is 9.0 though.

Comment: Using a 9.0 client and server, it did NOT write "Value is required" to the console.  I also copied to another server running 8.5.3 server and it also did NOT write it to the console.  I just pasted your code into an xpage, and didn't change anything else.  I hope that this helps with your troubleshooting.  It sounds like an server issue and not your code.  I just examined the server document of our server and couldn't find anything remotely like "Log Validation Messages".  You might consider renaming the question to attract any admins out there.

Comment: Many thanks Steve, appreciate your prompt response and many thanks for trying this. I will try a fresh install to see if that resolves this issue.

Answer (score 2):

A server side error triggers a log event. Depending on the logger settings this gets written to the console and/or log/trace files. When you check the settings in `data/workspace/.config/rcpinstall.properties` you find multiple entries like:

```
   com.ibm.esupport.client.product.SSC4TNF.utils.level=INFO
```

that determine what gets logged in what detail (it is always .level=SOMEUPPERCASEVALUE). Nothing to be concerned about.

Comment: Many thanks Steven, we will review this and try it on different servers as well.

Comment: The entry to use would be to change the validation logger from warn to severe only:
com.ibm.xsp.core.validation.level=SEVERE

Answer (score -1):

Your message control has no reference to your input field.

```
<xp:messages id="messages1" for="inputText1"></xp:messages>
```

I think this can be work.

Comment: Thanks but sorry, this is a global "messages" control, rather than a "message" control.